# I need get specific columns

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a model but i need get specific columns so i wrote native query

```
public interface HndAllOrgWipProdViewRepository  extends JpaRepository<HndAllOrgWipProdViewModel, Long> {
    @Query( value = "SELECT Transaction_Date, Class_Code, Start_Quantity, Transaction_Quantity,Fm_Department_Code from HND_ALL_ORG_WIP_PROD_VIEW where TRANSACTION_DATE  BETWEEN '01-Aug-2019' and '30-Aug-2019' AND CLASS_CODE = 'WORK WEAR'" , nativeQuery = true )
    List<HndAllOrgWipProdViewModel> fetchProcessPerformance();
}
```

Above query return array of arrays

```
[

 [
    "2019-07-31T19:00:00.000+0000",
    "WORK WEAR",
    500,
    83,
    "T5"
  ] ,
 [
    "2019-07-31T19:00:00.000+0000",
    "WORK WEAR",
    500,
    83,
    "T5"
  ]
]
```

but i need array of objects eg:

```
[

{
  Transaction_Date: "2019-07-31T19:00:00.000+0000" ,
  Class_Code : "WORK WEAR" , 
  Start_Quantity : "500" ,  
  Transaction_Quantity : "83",
  Fm_Department_Code : "T5" 

},
{
  Transaction_Date: "2019-07-31T19:00:00.000+0000" ,
  Class_Code : "WORK WEAR" ,
  Start_Quantity : "500" ,
  Transaction_Quantity : "83",
  Fm_Department_Code : "T5" 

}
]
```

Please also suggest is this a right approach or it there any other standardized method to do this.

Comment: Can you share `HndAllOrgWipProdViewModel` class.

Answer (score 0):

In HndAllOrgWipProdViewModel model there is Array object, Just make it simple Object. problem will be solved.